# NativeSearchQueryBuilder with spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to make search with NativeSearchQueryBuilder it works but when I add filter it doesn't work

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(queryString(query))
            .withFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("domain", "TEST"))
            .build();
    Page<Asset> asset =
            elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery,Asset.class);
    return asset.getContent();
```

the entity Asset.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ASSET")
 @Document(indexName = "asset")
 public class Asset implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "domain")
private String domain;

//getter and setter
```

}

test data

```
  id;name;domain
   1;name1;TEST
   2;name2;TEST
   3;name3;DEMO
   4;name4;DEMO
   5;name5;TEST
```

Can anyone help me where is the error please?

Answer (score 0):

i think your query must be:

Json Version:

```
{
  "query": {
     "filtered": {
        "query": {
           "query_string" : {
              "default_field" : "content",
              "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "domain": "TEST"
            }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

`NativeSearchQueryBuilder` Version:

```
QueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = queryStringQuery(query);
FilterBuilder filterBuilder = termFilter("domain", "TEST");
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(boolQueryBuilder, filterBuilder);

Page<Asset> asset = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, Asset.class);
return asset.getContent();
```